# Why does the Citrix Workspace installer fail on macOS 15 (Catalina)?

Tags: catalina, migration-assistant

I tried to install [Citrix Workspace v2002](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/mac/workspace-app-for-mac-latest.html) on a new MacBook Air running macOS 15 Catalina. I think the owner of the computer had used Migration Assistant from an old MacBook Air running a significantly older OS.

The installer failed without a user-facing explanation. Other versions of Citrix Workspace and Citrix Receiver also failed to install.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: is this a 32-bit application, or does it have any 32-bit components?  That would be an easy explanation as to why the install is failing under Catalina

Comment: Thanks Matt I did consider that. See my own answer below for the cause and workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The installer log view showed that a *File Not Found* error was occurring in `/private/tmp`.

Inspecting directly, `/tmp` was a symlink to `/private/tmp`, which itself was a symlink to `private/tmp`, that is to say `/private/private/tmp`! This target did not exist. The erroneous symlink had a modification date in 2016, which made me suspect a problem relating to Migration Assistant.

I think [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) was preventing me from modifying `/private/tmp`, even as sudo and with *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Full Disk Access* granted to Terminal.app . I didn't really want to disable it.

In the end I just created the missing target `sudo mkdir -p /private/private/tmp` and the installer worked.

It'd be nice to know how the erroneous symlink came into existence. The Migration Assistant theory is just a theory at this stage.

**addit**

Problem recurred while upgrading to macOS 10.15.4 (presenting with *An error occurred while updating firmware.*). Booted into recovery mode and inspected `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/private/` to find that my `./private/tmp` directory wasn't there any more. SIP seemed to be off so I could just remove the `./tmp` symlink and create a real `./tmp` directory. Then upgrade worked!

Hopefully this will be a more durable fix.