# Google Chrome fails to start with error: "Cannot Open. Cannot reach Citrix Workspace."

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome fails to load on Mac OS, with the following error:

[image: Google Chrome error: "Cannot open. Cannot reach Citrix Workspace."]

It says:

```
Cannot open. Cannot reach Citrix Workspace.
```

And there is a floating loading windowlet underneath, with a spinner that says:

```
Starting Google Chrome...
```

And it has a `Cancel` button.

I used to have Citrix Workspace from working with a client, which is a shitty VPN thing that nobody should ever use. It has since been deleted, but it looks like I'll have to do some digging to rip it out completely.

Does anyone have an idea for how to fix this?

Comment: Have you already tried to open Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled? P.S. I'm wondering if this gives you some hints: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/384074/274411

Answer (score 1):

I had two versions of Google Chrome installed on my system, and Spotlight was defaulting to opening the crappy Citrix-infected one, so I just deleted it.